# The Request body must contain the following parameter 'client_id'

Tags: api, azure, single-sign-on, onedrive

I have setup a Azure AD application for single-signon. I followed Microsofts tutorial https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm to set this upp and it all works fine, most of the time.

Sometimes when the user is trying to login to recieve the callback code the authorization fails and a redirect is performed back to the previous loginpage. The redirect is perfomed by the Microsoft API. The problem is that the parameter "client_id" is sometimes lost in this redirect, even though it was sent in the first request.[see url in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ot5UJ.png)

Could this be i bug in the OneDrive API?

Answer (score 0):

in screenshot i see the clientid is missing in url, you need to provide the clientid of your AD app.